# how to restrict user to write only one javascript function(method) inside of ui-ace editor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is my controller code

```
  $scope.aceOptions = {
      workerPath: 'http://localhost:50871/Scripts/app/vendor/',     
      useWrapMode: true,
      showGutter: true,
      theme: 'chrome',
      firstLineNumber: 1,
      onLoad: function (_editor) {
          $scope.script = {};
          $scope.script.scriptCode = "function fieldName_columnName_" + "functionName(){\n\n\n}";             
          var _session = _editor.getSession();
          _session.setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
          var _renderer = _editor.renderer;

          _session.on('changeAnnotation', function () {
              $scope.annotations = [];
              $scope.annotations = _editor.getSession().getAnnotations();
          }),
          _editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;

          _session.on("change", function (e) {               
              var currentValue = _editor.getSession().getValue();
              $scope.script.scriptCode = currentValue;
          });


      },
      require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
      advanced: {
          enableSnippets: true,
          enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: true
      }
  }
```

i wrote directive for ui-ace this is my html code

```
 <javascript-editor code="script.scriptCode" ace-option="aceOptions"></javascript-editor>
```

and directive code is

```
SCSApp
.directive('javascriptEditor', [
    function () {          
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=code',
                aceOption: '='
            },
            templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/shared/directives/javascripEditor/partials/javascriptEditor.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            }
        }
    }]);
```

and this is my javascriptEditor.html

```
<div class="e1" ui-ace="aceOption" ng-model="data"></div>
```

i just want to restrict user not to write morethan one javascript function in ui-ace editor

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own javascript simple function parser or use a lib like [parser3](http://silentmatt.com/parser3.js)

Then write  logic rules to show the success/fail to the UI based on the content of the ACE editor.

It is string / sentences parsing like compilers do in order to create the low level code.

Comment: i could you please do it in plunker i did'nt get you, i am new to ace editor

Comment: @SyedRasheed  This is an example of get ace editor code value and run some logic (Your own simple parser) http://plnkr.co/edit/KF9TNnu7nwXo283Hqm9w?p=preview As i said in the answer you can use a more complex lib wich is designed for javascript code parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach js function which would be triggered on keyDown or onBlur events within text editor.
That function should perform checking of text in editor for function declaration statements by [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).
If you would find more than one match of function declaration you could handle case when more than one function declared within text editor.